# Command to get usage % per CPU/core?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

Is there a command I can use from the Terminal on OS X to get the usage percentage per CPU/core **in numerical format** on my dual-core iMac?

I'm going to need to grab this every 5/10 seconds so I'm looking for something "low-cost" - that isn't going to hit the CPU too hard. Maybe something like `top`, but which shows both CPU/cores, that I can parse and then display in GeekTool;

```
Core 1: 11%
Core 2: 7%
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a wonderful extension to top, called `htop`, which shows real-time graphs per CPU in the top-left of the display, as well as many other controls and great customisability:

[image: htop]

You can install it with any of the following:

- [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) via `brew install htop`
- [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) via `port install htop`

There is a tutorial on how to get an htop port built for OS X:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100924083315/http://geektechnica.com/2009/07/how-to-install-htop-on-osx/

http://github.com/AndyA/htop-osx/tree/master

Comment: The title bar, it burns!

Comment: htop needs to be updated for Snow Leopard:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/21036

Answer (score 4):

Top shows individual cores, you only have to press '1'. I think there's also an option to change the refresh rate.

Comment: OS X's top doesn't have this nice Linux-y feature.

Comment: didn't know that, I expected it to be a standard feature

Answer (score 0):

There's an updated htop project at [Github by Hisham Muhammad](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop) , who has more info on [his site](http://hisham.hm/htop/).