# Writing CPU usage by core and RAM/CPU usage by process to a logfile in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, logging

I am writing a script that writes memory and CPU usage to a log file, every hour on a cronjob. The logfile will look something like this:

> "/n====CPU usage by core===="
>
> Core0: 59.05% used
>
> Core1: 57.68% used
>
> "/n====RAM/CPU usage by process===="
>
> PID | RAM used (KB) | %CPU used | COMM | USER
>
> 01 | 00003352 | 0.15% | /sbin/launchd | root
>     11 | 00009220 | 0.65% | /usr/libexec/Use | root
>     12 | 00005504 | 7.81% | /usr/libexec/kex | root

It will most likely use one command for CPU usage by core and another command for RAM/CPU usage by process, but I could use one command for both or more than two total commands.

The following commands that show some or all of the data I need, but unfortunately they are non-solutions:

- `top` has no `-b` command on OS X, unlike in Linux. This means that is auto-refreshes and is thus unsuitable for writing to a log file. [Command to get usage % per CPU/core?](https://superuser.com/questions/27954/command-to-get-usage-per-cpu-core)
- `htop` is an interactive program unsuitable for writing to a log file. And it shows CPU usage by core as an ASCII bar graph anyway. [Command to get usage % per CPU/core?](https://superuser.com/questions/27954/command-to-get-usage-per-cpu-core)
- `ps` can grossly underestimate memory usage, for example when pages
  are shared or when multiple applications use the same dynamically
  linked libraries. Otherwise, I would use `ps -eo "pid rss pmem
  pcpu comm user"`.
- `mpstat` isn't on OS X and isn't available from homebrew.

Having my user install homebrew from the command line is acceptable but having them building from source and having them manually add the commands to bash is not.

Also, all timing needs to be done in the cronjob so I can't use auto-refreshing commands and kill them after the first cycle.

Thank you for your help. :)